# VS code webview css variable names for used theme tokenColors

Tags: css, webview, colors, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I try to adapt the webview content to the used theme.

As explained in the [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#theming-webview-content) the used themes colors are exposed as variable names.

I can figure out the names for the colors by generating a [theme template](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme). So the variables match with the names in the generated json which are in the `colors` and can be addressed as explained `var(--vscode-editor-background")`.

Now i want to get the colors for strings, keyword etc. and this falls under the `tokenColors` and are Texmate colors, i cant figure out how to retrieve them.

The question is how can i get the ´tokenColors´ variable names?

And is it implemented jet or are only the colors exposed? [Implemented here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50489)

Answer (score 0):

The token colors are not exposed to webviews and are unlikely to be exposed in the future.

The reason is that the token colors are defined as Textmate theme rules, which are not well typed—i.e. there is not really a single `keyword` rule or entry—and can only be understood by a Textmate grammar engine:

```
{
    "name": "Variable and parameter name",
    "scope": [
        "variable",
        "meta.definition.variable.name",
        "support.variable",
        "entity.name.variable"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#9CDCFE"
    }
}
```

[This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/56356) tracks exposing VS Code's syntax highlighter to extensions